# Multiple IP ranges at DC, how do I set this up?

Tags: routing, switch, subnet

I have been tasked with a DC installation of ten servers. I myself, am a software engineer and not a network engineer (welcome to enterprise!), so I am a bit puzzled over this. I have been assigned the IP ranges, but these are two separate ones. To be precise (where the first 3 octets are the same for each):

1. xxx.xxx.xxx.32/29
2. xxx.xxx.xxx.48/29

I have been told the usable range in each of these is:

1. .33 – .38
2. .49 - .54

My question: Presumably, do I now have two default gateways that I need to configure. Some servers connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.32 and others xxx.xxx.xxx.48? The only network equipment at my disposal is an L2 switch. Is it just as simple as linking my equipment up to the L2 switch (some servers configured on one gateway and some another) and then on to the upstream switch/router? Will my switch support what is essentially 2 different subnets?

I sense I am missing a piece of crucial information to get this question answered.

Comment: I'm not sure what DC means in this context but the only two possibilities I can think of (District of Columbia or Domain Controller) don't seem relevant. Are those public ranges or private ranges? After you have connected these servers to the switch, who is supposed to be able to access them? Layer 2 switches don't know or care about subnets.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox, I believe DC is Data Center.

Comment: I'm assuming DC means "data center."  Do you have any info about the upstream router (or better still, access)?   Ideally, you would create VLANs for each subnet and route them to the upstream router.  What kind of L2 switch is it, and what kind or router?

Comment: I did indeed mean data center. These are public ranges, as all the servers are intended for use from the outside internet. Do the VLANS have to be setup at the router level as well as the switch level?  The switch is a TP-LINK TL-SG3424. The router: Unknown, I believe this at DC level and we are not expected to own one...although someone with more experience may blow my assumption out of the water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration on the switch depends on the router configuration.  If the router is configured with a logical interface (sub-interface) for each subnet, then you need to configure a VLAN for each subnet and trunk both VLANs to the router.  That means the uplink to the router will have both VLANs on it, using tagging to keep them separate.

On the other hand, if the router interface is configured with a primary and secondary IP address, then you do not need any configuration on the switch - a single VLAN will do.

In either case, there will be a default gateway for each subnet.

The advantage of the first method is that it gives you a mechanism to handle the two subnets differently.  For example, perhaps you want to apply a different security or QoS policy for each subnet.  If that's not the case (nor ever will be), then it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

To the question of default gateways: yes there will need to be a different gateway for each subnet, and that info should have been provided.

To the question of whether or not you can plug it in to one switch and expect it to work: there is no reason a L2 switch cannot carry two IP subnets (since it doesn't care about subnets at all) but in most enterprises, it is not done this way.  More commonly, a switch will have ports assigned to a VLAN and thereby two subnets will exist on specific ports on the switch.  If you were given specific switch port assignments for your servers, you will need to heed those with precision.  If you are providing your own unmanaged switch and you only have one port assigned from your enterprise, then it is probably a mixed subnet.

Comment: Thanks, this is making more sense now. Its clear that I need to clarify my setup with the data center, though I am quite certain that we will just be given one port from somewhere upstream, and we are expected to have unmanaged network HW. Provided I configure my VLANs correctly on the switch, is that all I need? Is it normal to rely on the DCs upstream router? And does VLAN configuration require extra config on the upstream router as well as the switch?